# Securing Typeform Webhook Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, typeform

I'm trying to accept form responses from Typeform using Python/Django/DRF and am having trouble authenticating the webhook request due to not being able to get the hashes to match.

Here are the instructions from Typeform:

```
1. Using the HMAC SHA-256 algorithm, create a hash (using created_token as a key) of the entire received payload as binary.
2. Encode the binary hash in base64 format.
3. Add prefix sha256= to the binary hash.
4. Compare the created value with the signature you received in the Typeform-Signature header from Typeform.
```

**authentication.py**

```
class TypeformAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        typeform_signature = request.META.get('HTTP_TYPEFORM_SIGNATURE')
        data = request.body
        secret_key = os.environ.get('TYPEFORM_SECRET_KEY')

        if not typeform_signature:
            return None

        if typeform_signature:
            hash = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf-8'), data, hashlib.sha256)
            actual_signature = 'sha256={}'.format(base64.b64encode(hash.digest()).decode())
            user = User.objects.get(username='typeform-user')
            if actual_signature == typeform_signature:
                 return(user, None)
            else:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Typeform signature does not match.')
        else:
            return None
```

**Example Payload**

```
{
  "event_id": "01DTXE27VQSA3JP8ZMP0GF9HCP",
  "event_type": "form_response",
  "form_response": {
    "form_id": "OOMZur",
    "token": "01DTXE27VQSA3JP8ZMP0GF9HCP",
    "landed_at": "2019-11-30T05:55:46Z",
    "submitted_at": "2019-11-30T05:55:46Z",
    "definition": {
      "id": "OOMZur",
      "title": "Auto Liability (New Company)",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "GnpcIrevGZQP",
          "title": "What is your business name?",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "3e60e064-f14c-4787-9968-0358e8f34468",
          "properties": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "answers": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "GnpcIrevGZQP",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "3e60e064-f14c-4787-9968-0358e8f34468"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Typeform Generated Hash**

`sha256=jdzKuFkijyBIMvmGyveHfcfzcNXUeQCuveNGP6CEdXk=`

**authentication.py Generated Hash**

`sha256=at4SsBIi2IXJ8vr1Ix3tHW7iK9q5KQfx20EBa+l9wKU=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working. Just in case anyone is having trouble authenticating webooks. I found this guide and adapted it.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/31/how-to-handle-github-webhooks-using-django.html

Instead of handling it inside of authentication. I changed to handling it with the view.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import base64
import os

@csrf_exempt
def inbound_application_create_view(request):

    header_signature = request.META.get('HTTP_TYPEFORM_SIGNATURE')
    if header_signature is None:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')

    sha_name, signature = header_signature.split('=', 1)
    if sha_name != 'sha256':
        return HttpResponseServerError('Operation not supported.', status=501)

    mac = hmac.new(force_bytes(os.environ.get('TYPEFORM_SECRET_KEY')), msg=force_bytes(request.body), digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
    if not hmac.compare_digest(force_bytes(base64.b64encode(mac.digest()).decode()), force_bytes(signature)):
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')

    return HttpResponse('pong')
```